Teams Addin - Side load - Static tab - Stage View
I can't open the stage view in the static tab if the application is loaded with side load in Teams. Stage view (modal) is not even displayed, clicks are ignored. No error is shown in the console. When using hardlink, a message is displayed that the URL does not exist. But the same URL works in the app added from the store.
The domain used in stage view is added to the manifest.
If the app is installed from the store everything is functional.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem?
I tried
    msTeams.stageView.open({
        "entityId": urlPart,
        "appId": appId,
        "contentUrl": baseUrl,
        "title": encodedName,
        "websiteUrl": baseUrl,
        "openMode": "modal"
    })

and
 let urlPart = appId + "/0?context={\"contentUrl\":\"" + baseUrl + "\",\"websiteUrl\":\"" + baseUrl + "\",\"name\":\"" + encodedName + "\"}";
 let url = "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/stage/" + encodeURIComponent(urlPart);
 msTeams.app.openLink(url);

I am using TeamsJs 2.21.0

Is this issue happening in New Teams or Teams classic? Could you please share the deployed app package or the repro video, so that it would be easier to analyse?

New Teams. There is nothing special in app package. Just static tab scope personal, context: personalTab ... video would show you nothing, just clicking on button, which do nothing on sideloaded app.

@Prasad-MSFT  I found out it is because of missmatch of id and externalId of used app. When app is sideloaded, there is generated? id and app id is pushed to externalId. If i use assigned id, stage view opens fine. Is this intended behaviour? Can I get this Id from TeamsContext? I can read it from GraphApi, but for that I need high permissions.

MS pointed me to the correct documentation, which actually says that the application ID changes depending on the type of application deployment.
     Type of app                    Type of app ID
     Custom app uploaded in Teams   Manifest ID
     Apps submitted to org catalog  Org catalog ID
     Apps submitted to Teams Store  Store ID

